# Connecting MS form to MS Excel workbook inside BOX folder using MS FLow

Tags: excel, forms, ms-office, box, power-automate

I am pretty new to MS Flow . I just got to know about it. I have a MS Form where i usually download the response from Excel file and then copy it to another excel file and upload it in the box.

I would like to have some suggestions/ideas if there is a way i can do this automatically without having to download the excel response and directly update the excel file in the box folder? ***I am looking for answers something like highlighted in Green arrow.***

Please note: Every time i get a response, it should add rows in the same excel file. I dont want a new excel file to be created in the Box.

Your ideas/suggestions are very much appreciated.

[image: Pic]

Thanks,D

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by **"BOX folder"** but I guess it is just cloud storage platform like Dropbox or OneDrive (both integrates with MS Flow of course) so it could be done easily.

Firstly please check this MS Flow template: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/a8fe18d6de56498686db35d5cbde5a8a/track-microsoft-forms-responses-in-an-excel-online-business-spreadsheet/ because I think it covers about 95% of your question. Above flow requires connection to `Microsoft Forms` and `Excel Online (Business)`.

Flow steps:

1. `When a new response is submitted` in Form as trigger,
2. `Get response details` action,
3. Insert response details to spreadsheet using `Add a row into a table` action,
4. Done.

Comment: Hi Thanks, Box is cloud file sharing service for businesses just like dropbox.